# Is there a way to call the Mixin function in scss through another Function?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

[image]
[image]

How can i call the Mixin function "fw" through the function "Incl" which stands for include. I want to shorten the "include" statement every time I include any function. Is there any way that can help me like that?

Comment: as far as I know you can't do that in sass. But can do using js which surely will get complicated.

Comment: So sad to hear that. I always like to shorten the word "include" so I can use the Mixin function faster

Comment: A mixin is no different from a variable.  Are you forgetting that the sass file processes a CSS file and is not used in production? Speed is preprocessing is not really a thing